# How to delete isolated shader nodes from script?

Tags: node-editor

I'v added some nodes by `nodes.new`

```
#node_output = nodes.new(type='name')
```

and linked some with  `links.new`, after re-run the codes, some nodes were created repeatedly.

How to delete those isolated nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Remove unlinked nodes.**

Re "totally isolated" nodes *ie* no links in no links out

Go thru all links and add the to and from nodes to the linked node set. The unlinked nodes is the difference between all nodes and linked nodes.

```
import bpy

context = bpy.context
ob = context.object
mat = ob.active_material
#mat = bpy.data.materials.get("Foo") # material Foo
assert (mat is not None and mat.use_nodes), "No material or not node based"
linked_nodes = set()

for link in mat.node_tree.links:
    linked_nodes.add(link.from_node)
    linked_nodes.add(link.to_node)
        
unlinked_nodes = set(mat.node_tree.nodes) - linked_nodes
while unlinked_nodes:
    mat.node_tree.nodes.remove(unlinked_nodes.pop())
```